# How to deal with time values over 24 hours in python?

Tags: python, date, time, format

I'm dealing with a large amount of data that has both values and times (in strings). I am converting the string time values into datetime values with the following code:

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, " %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The only problem is that some of my data has the format: `24:00:00.004`. So some of the data is actually over 24 hours

Python is giving me this error:

> ValueError: time data ' 24:00:00:004' does not match format ' %H:%M:%S.%f'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `%H` parameter can only parse values in the range 0-23. You'll have to manually deal with those specific time stamps:

```
try:
     time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, " %H:%M:%S.%f")
except ValueError:
     time = time.replace(' 24', ' 23')
     time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, " %H:%M:%S.%f")
     time += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: It's fortunate that there was a space in front of the hours here to allow the use of `replace` instead of some more ugly solution using `re`.

Comment: @mgilson: in which case I'd have used `'23' + time[2:]` instead, perhaps combined with a `time.startswith('24')`.

Comment: `.replace()` has a `count` parameter too.  I often use that to avoid accidental secondary replacements.  For the no-space case, that might've worked too.

Answer (score 3):

Try parsing the hours separately:

```
hours, rest = time.split(':', 1)
time = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hours)) + datetime.datetime.strptime(rest, "%M:%S.%f")
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your data does not contain dates, but time spans, so you should maybe store your data as [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-timedelta.html) instead of `datetime`.

---

You can use [this](http://kbyanc.blogspot.de/2007/08/python-reconstructing-timedeltas-from.html) function to create a `timedelta` from your strings:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

def parseTimeDelta(s):
    d = re.match(
            r'((?P<days>\d+) days, )?(?P<hours>\d+):'
            r'(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d+)\.(?P<milliseconds>\d+)',
            str(s)).groupdict(0)
    return timedelta(**dict(( (key, int(value))
                              for key, value in d.items() )))
```

---

Parsing your time string `'24:00:00.004'` like this

> >>>t = parseTimeDelta('24:00:00.04')

would result in a timedelta represented like this

> >>> print t
>   1 day, 0:00:00.004000

Comment: `%f` matches microseconds, not milliseconds. Don't call `str()` unnecessarily.