# Changing the date in a datetime column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a imported a time series csv file into a pandas DataFrame, however there is a quirk in the time from the file. Midnight is set as '24:00:00', not '00:00:00' (which is how pythons datetime likes it).

To create a datetime column in pandas I've done the following (both 'Date' and 'Time' are strings):

```
df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
```

However, datetime requires the hour of time to be between 0 and 23. I can replace '24:00:00' to '00:00:00' with:

```
df['Time'].replace('24:00:00', '00:00:00', inplace = True)
```

But then this in fact the morning of that day, not the night. Ideally I would then add a day to the date except I can't work out how to do this. 
I want to say "Where 'Time' == '00:00:00' add one day onto the date". I've tried something like this:

```
df['Date and Time'][df['Time'] == '00:00:00'] = df['Date and Time'[df['Time'] == '00:00:00'] + timedelta(days = 1)
```

But that doesn't work (and looks horrible).

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075562/how-to-deal-with-time-values-over-24-hours-in-python) post out

Comment: It seems like I'd have to do that in a loop before then putting it into a pandas column. Certainly doable, just seems like there could be another easier way.

Comment: Well you could apply it as a function, only to values >= 24. Should not be inefficient at all

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493966/4418475):

```
import email.utils as eutils
import time
import datetime
def fix_datetime(d_time):
    ntuple=eutils.parsedate(d_time)
    timestamp=time.mktime(ntuple)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

df['Date and Time'] = (df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']).apply(fix_datetime)
```

Resultant column 'Date and Time' is of type `datetime64`.

If the date is of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD', we first convert it to the RFC 2822 standard like so:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda date: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d %b %Y'))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - eutils.parsdate(d_time) returns None when passed the d_time string. The datetime string is in the format '2015-01-01 01:00:00' and the parsedate can't seem to understand that?

Comment: Ah, I assumed it was of the form '01 Jan 2015'. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out an way to make this work although I'm not sure its the most elegant. Its kind of based on Sebastians answer so thanks!

```
def add_day(timestamp):
  if timestamp.hour == 0:
    timestamp = timestamp + timedelta(days = 1 )
  return timestamp

df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
df['Date and Time']  = df['Date and Time'].apply(add_day)
```